# TextRenderer.MeasureText return Width=0 for character "&"

Tags: .net, vb.net, gdi+, textrenderer

All is in the title. I try to create my own OpenGL font system, and I need to get the size of each character I want to include in a Sprite texture.
All works well and accurately, except for the character "&" (ascii 38). Even if I change the font, this character always return zero for the width. Height is good.

The strangest thing is that, if I try to measure the concatenation of "&&" (Chr(38) & Chr(38)), the result seems good !
I haven't check to see if the same code point in another range of the same font product the same error, so I don't know if the workaround "if char is "38" test the size on "38+38" will always work.

EDIT:
Sorry,I'm so stupid. I completely forgotten to say I'm under VB.Net (but can understand C#) and I use OpenGL with OpenTK for the binding.
TextRenderer is a class of GDi+. I use this to create my font texture. This is really not an OpenGL issue.

Comment: What is `TextRenderer`? OpenGL does not have any such functionality.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas: TextRenderer is part of .NET; lmgtfy

Answer (score 5):

The & is used in control text to declare the next character is a shortcut key.  For example, having a control with the text "E&xit" displays "Exit" with the "x" underlined and will activate when the user presses Alt+X.

To include ampersands in your measurement, use:

```
TextRenderer.MeasureText(text, font, Size.Empty, TextFormatFlags.NoPrefix)
```